# Tiled Map Services from Geowebcache in QGIS?

Tags: geoserver, qgis

Can QGIS consume Tile Map Services from GeoWebCache?

I know there is a article on the QGIS website which states that it does support tiled map services but it lists Tile Cache from Meta Carta labs and ArcGIS Tile Map Service. No mention of GeoWebCache, and unfortunately no luck so far in loading layers from GeoWebCache.

Does anyone know if GeoWebCache is an option or not for QGIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some have had some success. I'm currently trying QGIS 1.5 to access the GWC instance built into our GeoServer installation without any success.

http://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg06870.html

Comment: It looks like the people who have had success are running GeoWebCache separately, not using the GWC included in Geoserver. I'll give that a try!!

Comment: I spoke too soon. A connection URL like http://www.acme.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?tiled=true is now working.

Comment: Ha me to! I just typed this into qgis http://myserver:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?tiled=true& and it worked. I'm sure I had been pluggin that same URL in every time!